# Consecutive modal view controllers crashes the app on dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiviewcontroller, ios

From the root view controller, I display a modal view controller(FormSheet) which looks like popup on some user action, clicking on a button on top of the modal view controller(first) opens up another modal view controller(second FormSheet). This also looks like a popup. The second modal view controller has a close button and touch up inside event is written in the second modal view controller class. When the close button event handler, I call [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] to just dismiss the second modal view controller. But the app crases at this point. (Note: I have used storyboard to create the UI and transitions with ARC turned off). Please tell me what im doing wrong !

> the error message I receive is [myFirstPoppViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6895410

Answer (score 0):

This is bad design. If you are looking to create a view hierarchy then I recommend you look into using a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Doing so will allow you to navigate through layers and layers of views with back buttons and transitions handled for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !. The modal view controllers which I open are just  FormSheets which look like a popup, So I can not use UINavigationController for this case. I have edited my question after seeing your answer.

Comment: @saikamesh Well then you may want to look into sticking with the original view controller and just creating additional custom UIViews as your popups. This way you can animate them in or out as you please without having to even leave the original view controller. This will also open the door to easily making your own custom transition effects.

Comment: UIModalPresentationFormSheet is for the purpose of showing a modal view controller as popup. So I have used that for my two modal view controllers. There is a close button on first modal view controller also which dismisses the first popup with no issues.

Comment: @saikamesh my best guess is that it crashes when you call dismiss because once there's a second modal view iOS doesn't know which to dismiss.